# getting all the values of an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array.

`array_values()` only gets the first level. While I need to get all the values, or in other words, I need a function to convert a multidimensional array into a one-dimensional array.

My function looks like this:

```
`$array = array(
[0] => array(1=>"first value", 2=>"second value"),
[1] => array(),`
```

While I need to convert it into an array like this:

```
`$array = array("first value", "second value");`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using user defined function “array_values_recursive” we can combine the multi dimensional array values into single dimensional array.

The function is

```
function array_values_recursive($ary)  {
    $lst = array();
    foreach( array_keys($ary) as $k ) {
        $v = $ary[$k];
        if (is_scalar($v)) {
            $lst[] = $v;
        } elseif (is_array($v)) {
            $lst = array_merge($lst,array_values_recursive($v));
        }
    }
    return $lst;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
$array = array();
foreach($array1 as $key=>$value)
{
  $array = array_merge($array,array_values($value));
}
```